# Problem with lstlisting with background and highlighted code

Tags: formatting, listings

I have a code snippet with an overlong line, which breaks as desired.
Custom formatting is applied to parts the line. However, the background style is not applied to the second part of the formatted line.
**How can I fix this?**

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{
    backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
    breaklines=true,
    escapechar=~
}

\newcommand{\highlightInListing}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor[rgb]{1,0.41,0.13}{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
 public static void x() {
    System.out.println("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" + ~\highlightInListing{compute(10000000, 44444444444, 333333333, 999)}~); 
 }
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If the escape part is `~$\displaystyle\frac{1138721637}{274618763}$~`, you will see the problem more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All what you need is to read section 7.2 of the `listings` manual. It is named: **Listings with a background colour and LaTeX escaped formulas**

[image]

So, the only workaround here is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{moreverb}

\begin{verbatimwrite}{x.java}
 public static void x() {
    System.out.println("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" + ~\highlightInListing{compute(10000000, 44444444444, 333333333, 999)}~); 
 }
\end{verbatimwrite}

\lstset{
    breaklines=true,
    escapechar=~
}

\newcommand{\highlightInListing}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor[rgb]{1,0.41,0.13}{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=lightgray,hidealllines=true]
\lstinputlisting[mathescape]{./x.java}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image]